# Using spaCy for finetuning a NER model in spaCy 3.0

Tags: spacy-3

I want to use `en_core_web_trf` model in spaCy library for [Named entity recognition](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities). However, the [guide for training](https://spacy.io/api/cli#train) a custom model does not contain information for finetuning a pretrained model.

How can one finetune an NER model in spaCy v3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's recommended you train your NER component from scratch rather than fine-tuning the existing model, because fine-tuning the existing model is prone to catastrophic forgetting. Note that even if your NER component is trained from scratch, you're still using the Transformer as a starting point, so you aren't starting from nothing.

More details about why not to re-train the existing NER, and how to do it if you want to, are in [the FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226). There are also many threads about this topic in the Discussion in general.

Comment: > "you're still using the Transformer as a starting point"

Here is the output of running `!python -m spacy init config config.cfg --pipeline="ner" --optimize="accuracy" --force`


`ℹ Generated config template specific for your use case
- Language: en
- Pipeline: ner
- Optimize for: accuracy
- Hardware: CPU
- Transformer: None
✔ Auto-filled config with all values
✔ Saved config
config.cfg
You can now add your data and train your pipeline:
python -m spacy train config.cfg --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy
`

Comment: As you can see, Transformer is apparantly None, this makes me think if I am really using a transformer model.

Comment: You need to add the `-G` command, indicating you'll use a GPU, for that command to generate a transformer config. Using Transformers without a GPU is not recommended.

Comment: Hey @polm23, I want to fine-tune the coreference model for my own custom data, does spaCy provide any such functionality?